# Auto generate a summary from strings

Tags: php, algorithm, text-processing

Given an input of strings we need to generate a very simple form of summary by trimming off the end of the strings into a given length.

Here is a first version function:

```
// Take an array of strings and generate a summary within a given length
function stringSummaryFromMetadata($inArray,$len=80,$sep='§'){

    // Filter out 'false' values
    $inputs=array_filter($inArray);

    // First try just imploding array
    $res=implode($sep,$inputs);

    // Check for length
    if(mb_strlen($res, 'utf8')>$len){

        // Calculate 'z' the fixed width constant
        $x=count($inputs);
        $z=round(($len-$x)/$x);

        // Snip all strings to 'z'
        $t1=array();
        foreach($inputs as $i) $t1[]=mb_substr($i,0,$z);

        // Final answer
        $res=implode($sep,$t1);
    }

    return $res;
}
```

A test:

```
$test=array(
    'Ligula diam risus tempus lorem sit',
    'Cursus metus commodo enim odio orci',
    'Metus sapien porta sapien fusce sodales',
    'king queen'
);
$out=stringSummaryFromMetadata($test);
print $out;
```

Which gives:

> Ligula diam risus t§Cursus metus
>   commod§Metus sapien porta §king queen

Thats good enough but it can be much more optimal I'm sure of that. For example, the test output is less than 80 letters, whitespace at the end of the string after trimming, words are chopped, etc.

Before I go off on a tangent and roll my own I would like to ask the community if this has been asked before and/or if an algorithm already exists for this.

Comment: `str_word_count` works better, especially, you do not want to break a HTML entities

Comment: @ajreal Not worried abot HTML entities. With str_word_count are you saying showing most frequent words is a better way to show the summary?

Comment: no, the purpose if to get an array with number of words, you can do a loop to check how many total of the combine words length won't exceed certain lengths, if exceeded, exclude from the position/word onwards

Answer (score 2):

You may use [wordwrap](http://php.net/wordwrap) and then count how many lines are in the resulting string. If more than one, your text was longer than needed, so you append your separator to the end of the first line, and discard the other lines. If there's only one line, your text was shorter, so no trimming was done.

It seems that `wordwrap` is no utf8 aware, but there's a [comment](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php#94452) that shows a `utf8_wordwrap` working function.

Comment: We need the summary to include parts of all the input strings not just the strings at the start.

Comment: No, you didn't understand me. For each input string, `wordwrap` will return the string formatted to a certain maximum width per line. If some input string is too long, it will return in a multi-line string. You get the first line, append your separator and discard the rest of lines. And then do the same for every other input string.

Comment: I get you now. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 2):

You can also construct automatic text summarization algorithm as written in paper [Extraction based summarization using a shortest path algorithm](http://dr-hato.se/research/shortpath.pdf). This approach is not very hard to implement.

good luck!